# Expression Value not getting updated in the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing a chrome extension using angularjs. For the same I have a controller as follows:

```
app.controller('PageCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    this.pageTitle = "xyz";
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({ greeting: "PageDetails" },
        function (pageDetailResponse) {
            console.log(pageDetailResponse);
            if (pageDetailResponse.status) {
                this.pageTitle = pageDetailResponse.title;
                this.pageUrl = pageDetailResponse.url;
                this.pageFaviconUrl = pageDetailResponse.favIconUrl;
                status = true;
                console.log("Updated var pagetitle to "+this.pageTitle);
            }

        });
    }]);
```

The call `chrome.extension.sendMessage` in the above calls the function passed as argument asynchronously and I am sure it is called since I can see both the logs that I have printed in the function. On the html side, I have the following:

```
<body ng-controller="PageCtrl as page">
    <div ng-controller="TabsCtrl">
        <section>
            <ul>
                <li ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(tab.url)}">
                    <a href="" ng-click="tab=1">Save Page</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(tab.url)}">
                    <a href="" ng-click="tab=2">Snapshot</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(tab.url)}">
                    <a href="" ng-click="tab=3">Annotate</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>

        <div class="popup-body" ng-show="tab === 1">
            <h1>{{page.pageTitle}}</h1>
            <textarea></textarea>
            <div>
                <img ng-src="{{page.pageFaviconUrl}}" />
                <p>{{page.pageUrl}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When the html is loaded, I can see value `xyz` (the value I have initialized it with). `pagetitle` does not reflect the new value assigned in the callback function. Am I making a wrong assumption here that if we change the title variable in the controller, the change is not reflected on the view?

Comment: you need to apply digest cycle..as you are modifying scope outside angular context and also place `var vm=this;` outside function and use `vm` instead of `this` that will assure you are sharing same `context`

Comment: The things that you need to check here is, what is the value of `this` in the callback function, is it the controller. Also i think you would have to wrap the assignments into a $scope.$apply as the callback seems outside Angular context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run digest digest cycle manually by running `$apply` method on scope. As you are modifying scope outside angular context and also place var `vm=this;` outside function and use `vm` instead of this that will assure you are sharing same context inside the `function`.

> More better way would be use `$timeout` to apply digest cycle that
>   will run digest cycle but will not conflict with any currently running
>   digest

**Code**

```
app.controller('PageCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.pageTitle = "xyz";
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({
            greeting: "PageDetails"
        },
        function(pageDetailResponse) {
            $timeout(function() {
                console.log(pageDetailResponse);
                if (pageDetailResponse.status) {
                    vm.pageTitle = pageDetailResponse.title;
                    vm.pageUrl = pageDetailResponse.url;
                    vm.pageFaviconUrl = pageDetailResponse.favIconUrl;
                    status = true;
                    console.log("Updated var pagetitle to " + vm.pageTitle);
                }
            })

        });
}]);
```

Comment: This worked fine after I added $timeout injection. Also, I am not sure why, but chaning vm=this to vm=scope got me the results. Any difference?

Comment: @labyrinth yes..they both are very different from each other..using this inside angular controller will lead you to use `controllerAs` syntax and `$scope` variable are directly accessible inside your view..could you please upvote & accept answer..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the function gets triggered outside of angular's control, you will have to manually apply the changes.

Wrap your function like this:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({ greeting: "PageDetails" },
    function (pageDetailResponse) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            console.log(pageDetailResponse);
            if (pageDetailResponse.status) {
                this.pageTitle = pageDetailResponse.title;
                this.pageUrl = pageDetailResponse.url;
                this.pageFaviconUrl = pageDetailResponse.favIconUrl;
                status = true;
                console.log("Updated var pagetitle to "+this.pageTitle);
            }
        });
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Pankaj's solution works just as well. Wrapping the function in the apply or just calling apply at the end both works. The advantage of wrapping the function is that if your handing function has multiple exit points, it still gets applied.

Comment: I got the point! Thanks for correcting.. but now I am getting this error Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

Comment: @labyrinth then you need to use `$timeout` which is one of safest way to apply digest.. Look at my edit in answer